# Triggering two page at once in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, buffering

Suppose, I have four pages (index.php, progressbar.php, buffering.php, trackvalue.php). What I want to accomplish is,

**1**

when someone will submit a value from index.php it has to be landed in progressbar.php.

**2**

progressbar.php will will grab current status value from a txt file created by buffering.php.

**3**

buffering.php will receive value from index.php while submitting value at first. And this page will output progress value in a txt file.

So I have to trigger and send the value to buffering.php while someone clicks the submit button but also have to land in the progressbar.php not in the buffering.php. Don't tell me just to include the prgressbar.php in buffering.php because I have to capture real time data from this page. And as buffering is enable in buffering.php I can't do that. Also don't tell me to disable output buffering, for some reason I can't do that.

Please suggest me how can I trigger a script in the background along with passing some value.

Comment: Google and study about AJAX first before you try to write some codes. Also have a look at jQuery's `.ajax()`

Comment: I have tried that. When I am processing something from a script it doesn't output anything till the process is done. That's why I am creating a txt file for real time data. If you know how to access a script while it is being processed through ajax please tell something about it. @LihO

Comment: If you have tried something, then question here should show what you have tried and describe concrete problems that you were facing...

Answer (score 2):

> Please suggest me how can I trigger a script in the background along
>   with passing some value.

The PHP page does have to finish processing before you get a complete return.

To do what it sounds like you are trying to do, you need do create some event-driven code.  You could do this by doing something like the following:

Don't have index.php communicate with buffering.php directly.  Have it deal with some new file, initiate.php.  When you make the request to this page to "initiate" your processing, have it create an Event entry in an event database table.  Then, have initiate.php just return the EventID that was created...not actually do the buffering.

Turn buffering.php into a cron process that looks through the Events table, finds new entries, and starts your processing in the background. If desired, it can update the row with a % complete, etc.

progressbar.php can then receive an EventId, query for the % complete in the DB and return that value to index.php, so that you can show progress while it waits for the cron process .  When it's complete, redirect or load whatever your complete data is to display to the user.

The main point is that you need some background process that can pick up an event from the scripts you are currently using, so that nothing you call from index.php has to wait for the entire process run-time.

This could be done with a MessageQueue system, with in-memory system like MemCache, or with the DB table as I described...